# Как остановить все плееры при клике и запустить текущий (YouTube Player API)?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос в следующем.
Есть 3 фрейма

```
<iframe id="video0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4DMGfbje7NY?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <iframe id="video1" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nJl-qVoEEJI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <iframe id="video2" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JyNIJ8U03I0?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Если их не обрабатывать js, то работать будут все плееры при клике на старт (одновременно).
А было бы здорово при клике на старт, чтобы все плееры затухали, а текущий (кликнутый) стал работать.

Есть дока, но в доке пока я пока нашел информацию про один плеер на странице. +Как остановить все(если были запущены ранее) тоже непонятно мне. ДокДок.

Прошу помощи у знатаков.
Перепробовал англоязычные варианты собратьев, многое уже устарело и у меня не заработало.

Пробовал и через Jquery... но тоже не вышло, да и нагружать лишним не хочется..

Answer (score 0):

Специфический вопрос. Вам нужно найти то событие клика которое отслеживается на ту кнопку которая вам приходит с этими iframes.(Судя по описанию она записана на класс, потому все и стартуют одновременно) Потушить это событие через `event.preventDefault();` а потом цеплять уже свою инициализацию фреймов.

Я бы рекомендовал вам отказаться от этой идеи. И делать правильное подключение Youtube роликов, как описывают [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JS70KB9GS0)

Comment: В приведенном видео есть ссылка на готовый вариант (https://pepelsbey.github.io/playground/12/after.html), одно но, все видео можно запустить сразу. Нет паузы между переключениями =( Про данный способ с подменой картинки + фрейма я знаю. Вопрос только в переключении между видео с паузой предыдущего.